# What is this covered-up electric box, with only white wires inside, for?

Tags: electrical, wiring, usa

I've got a covered up electric box, and inside are two white wires, both coming from the same place that are tied together. Neither of them register on my voltage tester. Taking the tape off reveals that inside each white wire is an even smaller red, green, yellow and black wire.

I'm mostly just curious what they might be for and why they have their own box like that. They also seem to just be taped together which I have to imagine is an issue. Any reason for me to not just swap it out with a more appropriate connector?

[image: picture of cover plate over electric box]

[image]

Comment: Using a better connector/cover for the wires is good.  Having two white wires is odd without their matching/pair of black(red) wires.  Do you know if the house uses cables or conduit?

Comment: I've not seen conduit anywhere inside.  There appears to be some going to the shed though

Comment: a lost 3 way switch

Comment: There might have been a reason with conduit(separate wires), but cable always has at least black and white together.  Conduit to outside buildings is usually recommended.

Comment: I'd look for a smaller blank plate; that corner over the panel joint would drive me nuts.

Comment: Looks like it was cut in later. Maybe a fish access point for retrofitted grounds? What's the era of the home? Does the original wiring have ground conductors?

Comment: home was built in 1983.  I've been slowly replacing a lot of switches in the house with z wave switches and all the switch boxes I've seen so far have grounds.  Not all of them have neutrals though which has been annoying to deal with

Comment: Just wondering if these are not phone/coax/internet cable/wires, instead of white electrical wire

Comment: Phone wiring was also my guess, but the picture does not show the guts. If you take the tape off and find red green black yellow wires in the cables, that's what it is.

Comment: We need to see the ends. Take the cover off and attach a pic. Could be network cable or coax (antenna). Doesn't look like power. The ends will tell us for sure.

Comment: taking the tape off revealed that inside each white wire was an even smaller red, green, yellow and black wire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Red, green, yellow, black wires in a cable make this "telephone quad cable," almost definitely used at present or in the past for landline telephone wiring.

[image]

Why's it there? This was a good place for a former owner/technician to put a junction. May have been easier to pull from both ends to this box, may have needed to tie in a line nearby and wire already ran through here.

What to do about it now? I recommend leaving it. Landlines aren't used nearly as often now, but are still present in nearly all older (and some newer) homes. The wiring can be repurposed in surprising ways, like carrying signals or voltage to security systems and smarthome devices. You can repurpose this wire for one of those uses if you have smarthome devices to place near there.

Alternatively, you could pull it out; but you'd likely want to fix that hole after you did, and it'll be difficult to get it to look good (smooth) without replacing that entire board.

As some others have commented, feel free to get a smaller cover plate if it'd look better to you. Although I think the reason that one's there is to cover up some sloppy cutting around the edges of the hole.

Answer (score 1):

That is telephone cable (four-conductor).